# How to notifyDataSetChanged after Asynctask In Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm unable to call notifyDataSetChanged without the application crashing.

ListFragment class:

```
public class ServerListFragment extends ListFragment implements OnTaskCompleteListener {


  private AsyncTaskManager mAsyncTaskManager;
private ServersDataSource datasource;
private ArrayList<Server> servers;
  private boolean paused = false;
  private boolean generateList = true;
    private String operation = "";
/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

/**
 * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
 * clicks.
 */
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

/**
 * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callbacks {
    /**
     * Callback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/**
 * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
 * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
 */
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public ServerListFragment() {
}
/*
 * Default list adapter
 */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // retainInstance and survive on configuration changes (rotation)
    setRetainInstance(true);


    // Create manager and set this activity as context and listener
    mAsyncTaskManager = new AsyncTaskManager(getActivity(), this);
    // Handle task that can be retained before
    mAsyncTaskManager.handleRetainedTask(getActivity().getLastNonConfigurationInstance());

    // start async task
    getServersServices();


}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(
            activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                    : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}

public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    ((BaseAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void getServersServices() {
    datasource = new ServersDataSource(getActivity());
    datasource.open();
    datasource.emptyServersTable();
    operation = "GetSevers";
    mAsyncTaskManager.setupTask(new Task(getResources(), getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.refreshing), operation, 0, ""));
}


public void onTaskComplete(Task task) {
    if (task.isCancelled()) {
        // Report about cancel
        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "ServersStatus onTaskComplete task cancel");
    } else {
            // Get result
            Boolean result = null;
            try {
                result = task.get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 if (DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "ServersStatus onTaskComplete error: " + e.toString());
            }
            // Report about result
            servers = datasource.getAllServers();
            if(servers.size() > 0 && generateList){
                DummyContent.setContext(servers);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        operation = "";
    }
    generateList = true;
}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // Get extra data included in the Intent
       String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
       if (message.equals("Refresh list")) {
           servers = datasource.getAllServers();
           getServersServices();
       }
    }
};
}
```

Error log:

```
> 09-30 15:15:39.360: E/AndroidRuntime(14322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 09-30 15:15:39.360: E/AndroidRuntime(14322):
> java.lang.NullPointerException 09-30 15:15:39.360:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14322):  at
> com.ww.www.ServerListFragment.notifyDataSetChanged(ServerListFragment.java:307)
> 09-30 15:15:39.360: E/AndroidRuntime(14322):  at
> com.ww.www.ServerListFragment.onTaskComplete(ServerListFragment.java:385)
> 09-30 15:15:39.360: E/AndroidRuntime(14322):  at
> com.ww.www.core.AsyncTaskManager.onComplete(AsyncTaskManager.java:67)
> 09-30 15:15:39.360: E/AndroidRuntime(14322):  at
> com.ww.www.core.Task.onPostExecute(Task.java:330) 09-30 15:15:39.360:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14322):  at
> com.ww.www.core.Task.onPostExecute(Task.java:1) 09-30 15:15:39.360:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14322):  at
> android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631) 09-30 15:15:39.360:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14322):  at
> android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) 09-30
> 15:15:39.360: E/AndroidRuntime(14322):    at
> android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
> 09-30 15:15:39.360: E/AndroidRuntime(14322):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-30
> 15:15:39.360: E/AndroidRuntime(14322):    at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-30 15:15:39.360:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14322):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898) 09-30
> 15:15:39.360: E/AndroidRuntime(14322):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-30
> 15:15:39.360: E/AndroidRuntime(14322):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-30 15:15:39.360:
> E/AndroidRuntime(14322):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
> 09-30 15:15:39.360: E/AndroidRuntime(14322):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775) 09-30
> 15:15:39.360: E/AndroidRuntime(14322):    at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are using the example that eclipse gives regarding master detail flow with the DummyContent class, but you have removed this peace of code which is vital for this code to work

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1, 
                DummyContent.ITEMS));
```

put it back in the onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Unable to see adapter in your code. Please setAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

I don'd see ListFragment.setListAdapter being called anywhere. Which is the reason for the crash noticed here.

```
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    ((BaseAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Here, you are trying to get the List adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged(). Since there's no list adapter, it will result in NPE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in this method:

```
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    ((BaseAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I guess that `getListAdapter()` returns `null` because I cant see that you are setting any adapter to this ListFragment anywhere.